# How to re-commit after a rollback in git

Tags: git, git-merge, rollback

I had a set of changes in the `master` branch, then I had to roll it back to a previous tag from production and do a hotfix since I didn't want the set of changes to go into production yet. So what I did was, I branched out `backup` branch from the `master` to keep the set of changes in `backup` branch and then rolled back into the previous tag. Used the following set of commands :

```
git checkout 1.0.1
git diff master > ~/diff.patch
git checkout master
cat ~/diff.patch | git apply
git commit -am 'Rolled back to version 1.0.1'
git push origin master
```

But now when I want to merge `backup` back to `master` since I intend to push the changes into Production. But im getting `Already upto date` message when I try to merge.

I do have the commit shas, but since theres a lot of commits to be done I want to avoid cherry picking them. Whats the best and safest way to merge the changes back to `master`?

Comment: "*I didn't loose the commit history by going the `revert`.*" You don't loose the commit history by doing the `revert`. You loose the commit history by doing the `reset`. What you did with `cat ~/diff.patch | git apply` is exactly `revert` just manually.

Comment: @phd right - im interested on a workaround hopefully avoiding cherry pick.

Comment: What's wrong with `cherry-pick`?

Comment: @phd theres a lot and getting merge conflicts

Comment: If `git apply patch` doesn't produce merge conflicts `git revert` or `git cherry-pick` most probably will not either. If `git cherry-pick` produces merge conflicts `git apply patch` most probably will do either. Doing `revert/cherry-pick` manually don't help to avoid merge conflicts IMO.

Comment: right - i just wanted to avoid since it looked bit tedious, but if its the only option I can give it a try. Is there any sequence of commits I should follow when doing the `cherry-pick` ?

Comment: You did `git diff 1.0.1 master` and it's hard to say without knowing your commit graphs and branches if that diff could be replaced with `cherry-pick` or `revert` — they do diff with the previous commit. If `1.0.1` is behind `master` then `git checkout master && git cherry-pick 1.0.1..master` should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap, currently:

1. There is a single commit on `master` which rolled back all of the changes since version 1.0.1. Let's call that commit `X`.
2. You have a branch `backup` pointing to the commit just before `X`.
3. There are probably some hotfix commits on `master` after `X`.

An example graph might look like this:

```
G    Merge Hotfix into master (master)
|\
| F  Hotfix Part 2
| |
| E  Hotfix Part 1
|/
X    Rollback to version 1.0.1
|
D    Fixup for Feature B (backup)
|
C    Merge Feature B into master
|\
| B  Feature B
| |
A |  Version 1.0.1 (Tag: 1.0.1)
...
```

Regarding:

> But now when I want to merge `backup` back to `master`... I'm getting "Already up to date" message.

Note that the way you did your rollback, (which was a fine way to do it), you added a single commit (`X`) which reversed all of the changes in the commits in `git log A..D`. Therefore, all commits present in the `backup` branch are already in `master`, so there are no new commit IDs to merge in.

**The easiest way to accomplish your goal is to revert the rollback commit.**

For example:

```
# Create a new branch from master
git switch -c revert-rollback master
git revert X # When prompted make your commit message
# add any other commits you need, if applicable
# Now you can merge revert-rollback into master
```

**Tip:** When reverting a commit, and especially when reverting a revert (which is kind of what you're doing in this case, since your patched rollback was like a set of reverts), I recommend adding details to the commit message explaining why you're doing it. So your commit message for the revert of the rollback might look something like this:

> Revert "Rollback to version 1.0.1"
>
> This reverts commit xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
>
> We originally rolled back to make room for a hotfix, and now we're ready to release the new code since v1.0.1.

Comment: Its a fine explanation. Thanks! Will try this